# How to exclude certain files in Qt based on a platform

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, qmake

I have a Qt application which I'd like to run on Linux, however it uses an API which is only available on windows. There are maybe 2 or 3 classes which make use of the API and I've tried to not tightly couple them with the rest of the program. I could obviously use a lot of `#ifdef win32` all over the place but I believe there should be a more Qt way of doing it within the .pro file.

Ideally I'd like qmake to detect the system and look for the API if it's win32. Then if it cannot find it or it's on a different platform, exclude the library and all the classes which include the headers from the API.

Here's an example of what I mean:

In.pro file I now have

```
SOURCES += main.cpp  \
           mainwindow.cpp \
           win32apiwrapperclass.cpp \
           ...

LIBS += "a/path/to/win32/only/lib -lwin32only

INCLUDEPATH += "a/path/to/win32/only/includes"
DEPENDPATH += "a/path/to/win32/only/includes"
```

Also in MainWindow.h I have something like:

```
private:
    Win32OnlyWrapperClass* win32owc;
```

and then win32owc is used in the cpp file a few times. So I'd like all of it excluded on other platforms as well. Hope it makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In .pro file you can do this:**

```
win32:LIBS += "a/path/to/win32/only/lib -lwin32only

win32:INCLUDEPATH += "a/path/to/win32/only/includes"
win32:DEPENDPATH += "a/path/to/win32/only/includes"
```

or

```
win32 {    
    LIBS += "a/path/to/win32/only/lib -lwin32only

    INCLUDEPATH += "a/path/to/win32/only/includes"
    DEPENDPATH += "a/path/to/win32/only/includes"    
}
```

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#scopes-and-conditions